# masterView does not always show/hide properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a splitViewController. This is in Detail VC

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.masterIsVisible = YES;
    //a botton in navigation bar to hide or show the master view.
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showOrHideMasterView)
    forControlEventsTouchUpInside]
    //gesture control to swipe right or left to slide master view in and out.
    [swiperight addTarget:self action:@selector(showMasterView)];
    [swipLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(hideMasterView)];
}

-(void)showOrHideMasterView
{
if (self.masterIsVisible)
    [self hidemasterView]; self.masterIsVisible = NO;
else
    [self showMasterView]; self.masterIsVisible = YES;
}

-(void)hideMasterView
{
    //hides master view by substracting masterview's width from its origin.x
}

-(void)showMasterView
{
    //shows master View by adding masterview's width to its origin.x
}
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:     (UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return NO;
}
```

Everything almost works as intended.
Problem: In one orientation && master is NOT visible.. then device changes orientation.. the master View instead of sliding off the screen pushed the detail view the other way. I know thats because the flag now is set as masterIsVisible = NO instead of YES. What can I do to change the flag to YES on device rotation. looks trivial but cant seem to figure out.

I tried registering for devicechnagenotification in UIDevice but that did not work. The BOOL is YES in any Orientation. The apple example uses this but looks like thats not the right approach here.

Comment: Why are you not using the Split View controller delegate method `- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
` ?

Comment: I am using it .I did not mention up there. Apologies. I returned NO for this delegate method.

Comment: What happens if you always return `YES` for that method?

Comment: I want the master view to show for any orientation rotation. So returning YES is not an option for me. However, returning yes also has same problem in reverse order. when master view IS visible + device orientation changes, the detail view slide the width of master view towards the left.

Comment: That is a very strange behavior for a split view controller. I have a bare bones project with a split view controller based on the master detail template from the latest Xcode and it works flawlessly. I am not sure what is causing this behavior that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured out to set the flag correctly for orientation change. I added the following method

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
  (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
 if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    self.masterIsVisible = NO;
 else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    self.masterIsVisible = YES;
 else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    self.masterIsVisible = YES;
 else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    self.masterIsVisible = NO;
 }
```